# Why tsc compile output a file that throw exception on running but ts-node run the ts file correctly?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-decorator

I write two ts files to test decorator.

index.ts

```
import { lockMethod } from './dec';
class Person {
  walk() {
    console.info(`I am walking`);
  }

  @lockMethod
  run() {
    console.info(`I am running`);
  }
}

const person = new Person();
person.walk();
```

dec.ts

```
export function lockMethod(target: any, name: any, descriptor: any): any {
  descriptor.configurable = false;
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "noUnusedLocals": true,
      "removeComments": true,
      "preserveConstEnums": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "lib": ["es7", "dom"],
      "baseUrl": "./",
      "paths": {},
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

When I run ts-node index.ts, it log the right thing `I am walking`, But when I compile it into js using `tsc -p .`, the result js contains an Error.

Below is the formatted js file.

index.js

```
"use strict";
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function(decorators, target, key, desc) {
  var c = arguments.length,
    r = c < 3 ?
      target :
      desc === null ?
        desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) :
        desc,
    d;
  if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function")
    r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
  else {
    for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (d = decorators[i]) {
        r = (
          c < 3 ?
            d(r) :
            c > 3 ?
              d(target, key, r) :
              d(target, key)
        ) || r;
      }
    }
  }
  return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};
exports.__esModule = true;
var dec_1 = require("./dec");
var Person = /** @class */ (function() {
  function Person() {}
  Person.prototype.walk = function() {
    console.info("I am walking");
  };
  Person.prototype.run = function() {
    console.info("I am running");
  };
  __decorate([
    dec_1.lockMethod
  ], Person.prototype, "run");
  return Person;
}());
var person = new Person();
person.walk();
```

When I run `node index.js`, the error is

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'configurable' of undefined
    at lockMethod (/Users/un/Documents/code/test/temp-ts/dec.js:4:29)
    at __decorate (/Users/un/Documents/code/test/temp-ts/index.js:20:15)
    at /Users/un/Documents/code/test/temp-ts/index.js:37:3
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/un/Documents/code/test/temp-ts/index.js:41:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
```

The logic in __decorate will omit the third argument (*property descriptor*) when arguments.length <= 3. So it causes my decorator not getting the *property descriptor* when code running. But what is the third argument of __descriptor mean? Why is there need to be a desc??

Why this happen? Is this related to tsconfig.json?

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure why the actual error occurs, but to answer the title question: 
Most probable reason that your code works is that ts-node ignores your tsconfig.json and uses a different build target, eg. not es5.